# how to create sqlite database or table from text file saved in sd card in android?

Tags: android

I have text file in sd card, In that First line contain column name for tables and rest of the lines contains values for the columns. Each line separated by /n, and each item separated by |. By using this i have to create a table in my database.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you have to create the database and the table that stores the data from the text file like below,

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";    

    /**
     * @param context Application Context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    /* Called when the database is created for the first time.
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DB_TABLE(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, content TEXT);");      
    }

    /* Called when the database needs to be upgraded.
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("DatabaseHelper", "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");     
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Then you have to read the text file from the SD card and insert the records to the table created above,

Define two variables,

```
   DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
   SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Initiate them in the onCreate method,

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Define methods to save the data to database

```
void saveDataToDB()
{
       File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

       //Get the text file
       File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

       //Read text from file
       StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            insertRecordToDB(columnName, columnValue);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
}

void insertRecordToDB(columnName, columnValue)
{       
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(columnName, columnaValue);

   db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
}
```